# Cryptic message from a former SYSOP

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

Your sysop recently quit due to what the law division calls "internal struggles". Less fancily, he hated you, and he hated his job. As a parting gift, he left you a program entitled SwanSong.c. Being curious and slightly daft, you of course decide to execute it. Your console immediately floods with errors to standard error output:

```
stderr
------
Line 4: Cannot exec a shared library directly.  
Line 5: Link has been severed.  
Line 5: Attempting to link in too many shared libraries.  
Line 7: Srmount error.  
Line 8: Too many users.  
Line 9: Name not unique on network.  
Line 14: RFS specific error.  
Line 18: Remote address changed.  
Line 18: Interrupted system call should be restarted.  
Line 18: Socket operation on non-socket.
```

**What does your sysop's swan song mean?**

---

<sub>Footnote: Bonus points if you can write a program that returns this output. I'm pretty sure it's not possible, and it's definitely not a requirement to solve the problem.</sub>

Comment: The bonus is easy... `print "Cannot exec a shared library directly" `... ;)

Comment: @Emrakul ah, yes, the old "hard-coded error messages" - I know thee well. :)

Comment: Are you sure these write to stdout and not stderr?

Comment: @IanMacDonald nope, not sure at all. In fact, they probably do print to stderr. It's not super relevant to the puzzle itself though.

Comment: Could probably leverage [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30169485/2708650) to get you to an executable that would output these error codes... however, you may want to do this on a machine you don't care about (like an easily-reflashable Raspberry Pi or something), just in case.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's not going to screw your computer up, only the program itself. ("Don't try in real products" because it has a good chance of not working and making your program crash anyway, and "don't try at home" because that's the meme)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are Linux error messages, which can be looked up here: http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html

```
83 (ELIBEXEC): Cannot exec a shared library directly
67 (ENOLINK): Link has been severed
82 (ELIBMAX): Attempting to link in too many shared libraries
69 (ESRMNT): Srmount error
87 (EUSERS): Too many users
76 (ENOTUNIQ): Name not unique on network
73 (EDOTDOT): RFS specific error
78 (EREMCHG): Remote address changed
85 (ERESTART): Interrupted system call should be restarted
88 (ENOTSOCK): Socket operation on non-socket
```

Convert the error numbers to ASCII to get the message:

> SCREWLINUX

Comment: Correctamundo. You get a fun little easter egg if you try to interpret this by line numbers instead, by the way. :)

Comment: Amusingly, I'm pretty sure some of these errors can never reasonably happen on Linux; `ESRMNT` and `EDOTDOT` seem to be Solaris-specific. Possibly the only reason they even exist is because Solaris has Linux binary compatibility, so a Linux app might on rare occasion encounter an error generated by the Solaris kernel :)

Answer (score 14):

For your bonus points, here's a (rather contrived) Perl program that will produce the desired output:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub ugh { $! = vec "SCREWLINUX", $x++, 8; warn "Line " . (caller)[2] . ": $!\n" }

ugh;
ugh ugh;

ugh;
ugh;
ugh;




ugh;



ugh ugh ugh;
```

Comment: +1 For making me laugh with all the ughs. Certainly the response I'd get out of a stream of errors that made no sense.